# Image and CSS URL paths not resolving to correct locations in browser

Tags: github, github-pages, relative-url

When I recorded the network activity of my project on https://zeddrix.github.io/bible-query/, and looked at the path of my **style.css**, the path should be like this: https://zeddrix.github.io/bible-query/styles/style.css to access my CSS.

But instead of having that, I keep on having https://zeddrix.github.io/styles/style.css without the ***/bible-query/*** that's why it can't be found.

The same happened with my images. For example, instead of having https://zeddrix.github.io/bible-query/img/play-btn.jpg, I keep on having https://zeddrix.github.io/img/play-btn.jpg without the ***/bible-query/*** on the URL again.

I was expecting to have this (on Live Server):

[image]

But instead, I keep on having this (on GitHub Page):

[image]

Please help me. Here's my repository: https://github.com/zeddrix/bible-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the first forward slash from all of the URL references. So, `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/style.css" />` would become `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" />`. This will turn it into a "relative" link, instead of an absolute link.